# Writing basic systemd service files

Tags: services, systemd

I am developing a Nodejs application that the user interacts with via HTTP on localhost. There are practically no parameters and the daemon has virtually no dependencies and it just needs to be up by log-in time.

I would like to follow the idioms on each platform for start-up scripts, and that means Upstart on Ubuntu and systemd on Fedora.

- **Are there any good tutorials for writing systemd system files?**
- **Are there any 'best practices' to be aware of?**

I have found these resources:

- [Fedora wiki page about systemd](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/systemd)
- [Blog about writing systemd system files](http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html)
- [Systemd on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)

I am mostly looking for an API of sorts as a reference, as well as a basic format to follow.

Comment: The [Arch Linux Wiki page about systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) has an interesting section about writing service files.

Comment: > man systemd.service
> > man systemd.unit

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would start with the [Systemd manual pages](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/). They represent a comprehensive resource of the system and services.

There is also the [freedesktop Systemd FAQs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Comment: The man pages will be useful (I wish it was cleaner though), but is there a basic system file tutorial? Like which parts are necessary, which parts are recommended, and which parts are optional. The man pages seem to assume that I'm already an expert in systemd system files, which I am not.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unfortunately. There is probably an assumption that if you are writing initscripts, you already know how to write initscripts. Look through the Arch scripts and pick one that is similar to what you need: http://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/systemd/

Comment: Thanks! With your help and the blog I found, I was able to get a basic one working. Systemd seems a lot nicer than upstart or the old systemv init daemon.

Comment: @tjameson, that is what man pages are *for*...

Comment: Who has time in there lives to START with that. I mean, if you know what you are doing that is a great reference, but holy cow the manual pages are complex.

Comment: @macmadness86 The OP was looking for an authoritative source (see the last para); for most needs, reading the service file for a similar app and then consulting specific parts of the `man` page will be more than enough to get you there. They are actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: @jasonwryan I know this is 5 years later, but, errr, the link you posted is broken. If I find where it is now, I'll edit this comment with it.

Comment: @JoaoMilasch Neither looks broken to me. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @jasonwryan: Gosh, sorry for not being specific enough. I meant the link in your comment: archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/systemd which is not in itself that important but I tried to follow it to find examples...

Comment: @JoaoMilasch Oh, yeah: `systemd` has moved to core: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/systemd/

Answer (score 193):

The following example is inspired by this link, which actually does not mention all steps and is listed just to credit the source: http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html

**Step 1**: I created this file (note location) which essentially fires a bash process with an extended argument. You could fire your own command which could be different from bash.

```
[root@y500-fedora ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/foo.service 
[Unit]
Description=foo

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "while true; do /bin/inotifywait -qq --event close_write /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness; su myusername -c '/bin/xbacklight -display :0 -set $(cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness)'; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step 2**:

Reload `systemd`:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the new service:

```
systemctl enable foo
```

(similarly you can `disable` it)

**(optional) Step 3**: It should start automatically at next reboot into multi-user mode (run level 3) but if you want to start it right away:

```
systemctl start foo
systemctl status foo # optional, just to verify
```

**Update:** For completeness, I should add that ubuntu bionic seems to have a very thorough man page. [RTFM here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)

Comment: systemctl has a cat command shortcut, for reference.

Comment: What is the cat command shortcut? Like a way to create and edit the systemd control files without entering the whole path?

Comment: what are the permissions this file should ideally have?

Comment: @knocte the permissions are moot, since it will be a privileged process that will be reading it and just reading it not writing. the location of the file is a privileged location (`/usr/lib/systemd/...`) and you will likely need some special permissions to add your file there.

Comment: According to systemd.unit man page, you should put it in `/etc/systemd/system`. /usr/lib/systemd is where the proper distribution packages put their files.

Answer (score 6):

The Redhat documentation is a great source.

- [CREATING AND MODIFYING SYSTEMD UNIT FILES on RHEL7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd)
- [MANAGING SERVICES WITH SYSTEMD | Introduction to systemd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd#tabl-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Introduction-Units-Locations)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @StephenRauch I know that plain links are not very welcome but this is a huge topic and it's not easy to summarize in a answer.

Comment: DigitalOcean also has a pretty comprehensive set of tutorials and associated documentation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal

Comment: First link gives a 404, second works well

Comment: @Naramsim Thanx, fixed

Answer (score 0):

The [Arch wiki's](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd#Writing_unit_files) page on writing systemd units is quite comprehensive and accessible.