# Systemd will not start xenstored, xenconsoled, and xendomains

Tags: systemd, gentoo, xen

I am running a Gentoo installation and recently moved to systemd and whenever I boot with Xen, I cannot issue any xl commands, getting this error:

> xc: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (2 = No such file or directory): Internal error
>
> libxl: error: libxl.c:92:libxl_ctx_alloc: cannot open libxc handle: No such file or directory
>
> cannot init xl context

After looking into the issue, I found that the three mentioned services (xenstored, xenconsoled, and xendomains) were not running and I could not enable them in systemd. I checked **/usr/lib64/systemd/system** for and service files with names even containing xen and none were found. So I believe I need to install those three services somehow, but I'm not sure why they were not installed when I emerged **xen (and xen-tools) or systemd**. Do I need to just build them from source? Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by just reinstalling xen and xen-tools while systemd was already installed.

I did, however, have to change my xen-qemu-dom0-disk-backend.service to point to my already installed QEMU binary (since I use a separate QEMU package).

Answer (score 0):

### Bad News

I looked this up a few days ago, and forgot to post the answer.  I don't use `xen` or `xen-tools` so my `emerge` output shows the extra packages:

```
ecyoung@bedroom-gentoo ~ $ sudo emerge -av xen xen-tools

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/yajl-2.0.4-r3::gentoo  USE="-static-libs" ABI_X86="32 (64) (-x32)" 81 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/markdown-2.6.1::gentoo  USE="-doc -pygments {-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_3 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 292 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/pypam-0.5.0-r3::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_3" 103 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-firmware/ipxe-1.0.0_p20130925::gentoo  USE="qemu usb -iso -undi -vmware" 2,188 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-devel/dev86-0.16.19::gentoo  697 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] net-misc/bridge-utils-1.5::gentoo  USE="(-selinux)" 33 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-emulation/xen-tools-4.5.0-r6::gentoo  USE="pam python -api -custom-cflags -debug -doc -flask -hvm (-ocaml) -ovmf -pygrub -qemu -screen -static-libs -system-qemu -system-seabios" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7" 18,604 KiB
[ebuild  N     ] app-emulation/xen-4.5.0-r8::gentoo  USE="-custom-cflags -debug -efi -flask -xsm" 0 KiB

Total: 8 packages (8 new), Size of downloads: 21,996 KiB

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No] n

Quitting.

ecyoung@bedroom-gentoo ~ $
```

---

As you can see from the output listed above the `systemd` USE Flag isn't listed in the USE list for either `app-emulation/xen` or `app-emulation/xen-tools`.  Every package that supports the `systemd` USE Flag will have it listed in the list.  In fact, we can verify this with the `app-portage/gentoolkit` package that contains the `equery` script:

```
ecyoung@bedroom-gentoo ~ $ sudo equery hasuse systemd
 * Searching for USE flag systemd ... 
[IP-] [  ] app-admin/syslog-ng-3.6.2:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-libs/efl-1.12.2:0
[IP-] [  ] kde-base/kdm-4.11.19:4/4.11
[IP-] [  ] media-gfx/sane-backends-1.0.24-r5:0
[IP-] [  ] media-sound/pulseaudio-5.0-r7:0
[IP-] [  ] net-print/cups-2.0.2-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] net-wireless/bluez-5.25:0/3
[IP-] [  ] sci-geosciences/gpsd-3.9-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-apps/accountsservice-0.6.40:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-apps/busybox-1.23.1-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-apps/dbus-1.8.16:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-apps/util-linux-2.25.2-r2:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-auth/pambase-20150213:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-auth/polkit-0.112-r2:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-fs/lvm2-2.02.109:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-fs/multipath-tools-0.5.0-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-fs/udisks-2.1.4:2
[IP-] [  ] sys-process/procps-3.3.9-r2:0
[IP-] [  ] virtual/libgudev-215-r3:0/0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[IP-] [  ] virtual/libudev-215-r1:0/1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[IP-] [  ] virtual/udev-215:0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[IP-] [  ] x11-base/xorg-server-1.16.4:0/1.16.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[I-O] [  ] x11-wm/enlightenment-0.19.4:0.17/0.19                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ecyoung@bedroom-gentoo ~ $
```

*Please note the list would include more if I had a systemd profile enabled.  See the Tracker Bug below for a more complete list.*

---

### Possible Fixes

Since the flag isn't listed above, that leaves you with about 3 options that I can think of:

1. [Write your own .service files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files). There are also numerous other links like [this one](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html), just Google for **writing systemd service**
2. Switch back to OpenRC/SysV init using `eselect profile` (Choose a profile without `systemd`).  This setup is well documented on the [Xen Wiki Entry for Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xen)
3. Contribute the `.service files` you wrote in #1 to [Bug 482420 - app-emulation/xen-tools: Add systemd unit script file support](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=482420), which blocks [Bug 448882 - (install-systemd-unit) [Tracker] packages not providing systemd units](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448882).  This list contains all the packages that need systemd units.  The ones that are <s>crossed out</s> have had support added.  The ones that aren't still need work.