# How to lump together Apache2 Server and xsp2 server in the configuration for auto start when the PC reboots?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, apache-httpd, mono

We need to lump together Apache2 Server and xsp2 server(or  mod-mono-server server) in the configuration for the auto start sample shown below when the PC reboots.

Quoting from the article, https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup

```
"sudo update-rc.d minidlna defaults
This should add the service to the automatic startup system. But if you get:

System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/minidlna already exist.
Do the command

sudo update-rc.d minidlna enable"
```

How could I adapt the above sample so that Apache2 Server and xsp2 server are lumped together during the automatic startup procedure?

I was thinking of launching Apache2 first directly followed by launching xsp2 next. Is this  possible to do with Ubuntu 16.04 or is there a better way?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That linked article is 6 years old.  Ubuntu has move on since then and now uses `systemd` to start services. `apache` will have the required files to start it automatically at boot, but you may have to write your own for `mono-xsp2`.

Comment: @garethTheRed, Thank you for your excellent comment. What is the and path of apache's required files to start it automatically at boot? What do I have to write for mono-xsp2? Why do we use mono-xsp2 instead of xsp2?

Comment: @garethTheRed, Thank you for your excellent comment. What is the name and filepath for apache's required files to start it automatically at boot? What do I have to write for mono-xsp2? Finally, why do we have to use mono-xsp2 instead of xsp2?

Comment: For Apache it's `systemctl enable apache2`. You could (probably) copy the apache `.service` file and change the `ExecStart` for `xsp2`.  I suggested `mono-xsp2` as the XSP package after a very quick Google - feel free to ignore that :-)

Comment: @garethTheRed, Here are some helpful reference URLs for this question: [Can I use xsp2 instead of apache with mod_mono as my regular web server application?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158665/mono-and-ihttphandler][1]
May I use apache2 to xsp2 on a standalone basis to serve ASP.NET content to browser users?

Answer (score 2):

I wish to thank @garethTheRed for suggesting to use systemd instead of update-rc.d

The URL [Writing basic systemd service files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files) contains this answer.

Step 1: I created this file (note location) which essentially fires a bash process with an extended argument. You could fire your own command which could be different from bash.

```
[root@y500-fedora ~]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/foo.service 
[Unit]
Description=foo

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "while true; do /bin/inotifywait -qq --event close_write /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness; su myusername -c '/bin/xbacklight -display :0 -set $(cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness)'; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
Step 2:

systemctl enable foo
(similarly you can disable it)
```

(optional) Step 3: It should start automatically at next reboot into graphical mode (run level 5) but if you want to start it right away:

```
# systemctl start foo
# systemctl status foo # optional, just to verify
```