# How to run a Executable file at boot time?

Tags: debian, boot, executable

I am using Debian OS I have one executable file (a.out), Now I need to run this file after boot up Immediately.

I tried with etc/rc.local.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, my suggestion is rc.local.

Comment: Can you please send me a sample code? How to add a.out file to rc.local file?

Comment: No, could you please provide sufficient information about what you have tried? Path to file, permissions of the file and so on. The exact line you added to rc.local.

Comment: Yes, and if you want help, you should provide more information. Exact line you added to rc.local, path to your a.out and the permissions of a.out.

Comment: yes, I gave full permissions of a.out file using chmod 755 a.out,  in rc.local file added line is    /home/user/script.sh

Comment: BTW, it is unusual and against conventions to name *today* some "system-like" executable as `a.out`  (which is very likely to be some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable). I strongly recommend to name it more meaningfully.

Answer (score 2):

**It greatly depends on your [`init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) subsystem**, which could be some sysvinit thing with [runlevels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel), some [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) thing, or something else (e.g. [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/)).

You need to investigate what `init` your computer (and distribution) has, and dive into the documentation of its `init` program.

Recent Debian distributions are generally using `systemd`. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files).

BTW, read about [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html). Perhaps a `@reboot` entry might be enough. You might use [crontab(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) to add it.

Notice that in `init` related scripts and in `crontab`  jobs, the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is *not* initialized from your user's settings (but has a *small* system wide default). Practically speaking, better use full executable file path in such things.