# creating a .deb package and autorun it

Tags: packaging, deb

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running the latest Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-11-13.

I built a program that communicates with a LoRa chip (SX1276) using SPI, gets some data from a temperature sensor and prints the temperature on the screen.

My program consists of only one executable (apart from wiringpi library).

I was searching for a tutorial to make my program a *.deb package. Using [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717) tutorial I managed to build a `lora.deb` package.

When I installed my `lora.deb` package `sudo dpkg -i lora.deb` the executable just deployed in a directory.

How can I make that package automatically run the executable and also run it every time the system boots?

Comment: Check out `systemd` service files. If your deb package contains a service file, and you add a postinstall script to your package, you can bring up a service after install automatically and on boot.

Comment: See here [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15348/96382) for guides to writing systemd unit files, which will be used by systemd (which handles startup) to start your service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change '/usr/bin/something' to '/directory/path/to/deployed/executable' below:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/something.service

[Unit]
Description = Something Service
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/something

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target

$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable something
$ systemctl start something
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Reading through all those sites and tutorials I came up to the solution for the whole method. First of all I need to add a `myapp.service` into my `*.deb` package, then I'll have to write a postinst script that will copy the `myapp.service` into the proper path and enable the service.
I'm not quite sure if instead of a copy you just have to add the `myapp.service` into the `*.deb` package with the proper path.

Comment: This is nice but it answers the question only partially. Where does this .service file go in the .deb file? How is the service activated by the .deb?