# systemd service not found

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

My operating system is Ubuntu Bionic beaver.

I have written a systemd serivce unit:

```
/etc/systemd/user# ll
total 20
drwxrw-r-x 2 rock64 rock64 4096 Nov 23 15:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 Nov 20 07:21 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 rock64 rock64   74 Nov 23 14:30 photon_uploader.env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rock64 rock64  463 Nov 23 14:50 photon_uploader.service*
-rw-r--r-- 1 rock64 rock64  175 Nov 23 14:57 photon_uploader.socket
```

but if I try enabling it I get error:

```
 systemctl enable photon_uploader
Failed to enable unit: Unit file photon_uploader.service does not exist.
```

I couldnt think of where to systematically put the service file , so I put it under user folder, and since I install service from a remote location , I rsync, and I have given the user folder ownership to non-root user. I

Comment: Did you run systemctl daemon-reload?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15348/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes even then I get the same error.

Comment: is the file permission and ownership has to do until I read the man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my userspace systemd service, I put my files in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user`. Then, I ran `systemctl enable --user my_service`.

Comment: well I created a symlink of `photon_uploader.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` from `/etc/systemd/user/photon_uploader.service` then I did `systemctl daemon-reload` and enabled it, and started it worked. But when I disabled it and try to reenable it, I again got error,  service not found, so I had to manually create the symlink again.

Comment: If you move your files to the directory I posted, you won't need to use symlinks.

Comment: gives me permission denied error while trying to rsync

Comment: Run `mkdir -p $HOME/.config/systemd/user; mv /etc/systemd/user/* $HOME/.config/systemd/user`, then `systemctl enable --user photon_uploader`.

Comment: didnt worked . the `systemd` fodler in `$HOME/.config` didnt existed so I created it.  but I got error `Failed to enable unit: Unit file photon_uploader.service does not exist.`

Comment: What does `ls -l $HOME/.config/systemd/user` show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101409/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-ciasto-piekarz).

Comment: `$ ls systemd/user/
multi-user.target.wants  photon_uploader.env  photon_uploader.service  photon_uploader.socket`